# Is there a way to get "<NA>" string printed by `kable`?

Tags: r, string, na, kable

I have a data frame with the string `<NA>` in a character column. If I apply `kable` to this data frame, that string does not appear. 
In fact, it has nothing to do with data frame as following example shows:

```
kable(c("a",NA,"b","<NA>","c","NA","d"))
```

First and last `NA`'s are printed (looking for my problem, I have already seen that it depends on `options(knitr.kable.NA`), but middle `<NA>` is not.

You can see below my input and output files with this test.

[image]

And session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Spain.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Spain.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Spain.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=Spanish_Spain.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[7] base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.2       rstudioapi_0.9.0 knitr_1.24      
 [4] magrittr_1.5     ggpubr_0.2.1     tidyselect_0.2.5
 [7] munsell_0.5.0    colorspace_1.4-0 R6_2.4.0        
[10] rlang_0.4.0      factoextra_1.0.5 highr_0.7       
[13] dplyr_0.8.3      tools_3.5.2      grid_3.5.2      
[16] gtable_0.2.0     xfun_0.8         htmltools_0.3.6 
[19] digest_0.6.20    yaml_2.2.0       lazyeval_0.2.2  
[22] assertthat_0.2.1 tibble_2.1.3     ggsignif_0.5.0  
[25] crayon_1.3.4     purrr_0.3.2      ggplot2_3.2.0   
[28] bitops_1.0-6     rsconnect_0.8.13 RCurl_1.95-4.12 
[31] ggrepel_0.8.1    evaluate_0.14    glue_1.3.1      
[34] rmarkdown_1.14   compiler_3.5.2   pillar_1.4.2    
[37] scales_1.0.0     pkgconfig_2.0.2
```

And RStudio Version 1.1.463.

Why? Is there an `option` to get it printed? Another way?

Thank you!

Comment: Middle one is not an `NA`. I don't think `knitr::kable` is intended to do any data-modification like that, that's on you before you send it to `kable`. For instance, you could `gsub("<NA>","NA",x)` to turn it into a literal `"NA"` string.

Comment: I know `"<NA>"` is not a `NA`, `"NA"` is not a `NA` too. It is just an example and a way to refer to it.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem--it prints for me. Is `knitr` up-to-date? `knitr::kable(c("a",NA,"b","<NA>","c","NA","d"))`. Also, looks like `options(knitr.kable.NA = )` changes how true `NA`'s are displayed in `kable`.

Comment: Yes, it is up to date. It is strange.

Comment: I can't reproduce it either using `knitr-1.23`: I see the first `NA` as per `knitr.kable.NA`, the second as `<NA>`, and the third a literal string `NA` (not controlled by `knitr.kable.NA` since it is a literal string).

Comment: @r2evans Since all you cannot reproduce my example I added an image with it and my session info.

Comment: You never said this was going into an HTML report, that changes *everything*. Try something like `knitr::kable(htmltools::htmlEscape(c("a",NA,"b","<NA>","c","NA","d")))`.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks! Would you mind to develope your answer and explain why this happens? (I see the idea, symbols `<>` are for tags in html....) It could be considered a bug of knitr::kable?

Comment: @r2evans There is another problem. My original object is not a vector, but a data frame. If I do `kable(htmltools::htmlEscape(data frame))` it becomes completely unformatted in the html output.

Comment: `kable` has a `format` argument you can use, try `kable(your_dataframe, format = "html")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two ways around this, choose based on the desired output:

R-markdown:

````
---
title: "testNA"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
df <- data.frame(a= c ("a",NA,"b","<NA>","c","NA","d"), b = 1:7,
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

```{r}
knitr::kable(df)
```

```{r}
knitr::kable(df, format="html")
```

```{r}
ischr <- sapply(df, function(a) is.character(a) | is.factor(a))
df[ischr] <- lapply(df[ischr], htmltools::htmlEscape)
knitr::kable(df)
```
````

[image: rmarkdown output, with broken, fix 1, and fix]